# widget that will do shortcodes that user inputs

Tags: widgets, code

I have this widget that im working on and it allows the user to input a shortcode and it will display it in the sidebar. But its not working right. I can input the short code but it has no output. Also it seams to strip the [] and if you include size=35, the 35 is stripped after you hit the save button. Here is part of the code:

```
     //Set Shortcode 1 title
    $sc1title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 1 Title', $instance['sc1title'] );

    //Display Shortcode 1 title
    if ( ! empty( $sc1title ) )
        echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc1title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

    //Do Shortcode 1
    //echo do_shortcode('sc1');
    //echo do_shortcode($this->shortcodes[$instance['sc1']]);
    echo do_shortcode('[sc1]');

echo "<br>";

    //Set Shortcode 2 title
    $sc2title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 2 Title', $instance['sc2title'] );

    //Display Shortcode 2 title
    if ( ! empty( $sc2title ) )
        echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc2title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

    //Do Shortcode 1
    //echo do_shortcode('sc2');
    echo do_shortcode($this->shortcodes[$instance['sc2']]); 

    echo $args['after_widget'];



    // Display after widget code
    echo $after_widget;
}

// Update the widget settings.
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['title']) );
    $instance['mtitle'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['mtitle']) );
    $instance['nav_menu'] = (int) $new_instance['nav_menu'];
    $instance['sc1title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc1title']) );
    $instance['sc1'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc1']) );
    $instance['sc2title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc2title']) );
    $instance['sc2'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc2']) );
    return $instance;

}

// Displays the form on the widget page
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
    $nav_menu = isset( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? $instance['nav_menu'] : '';
    $mtitle = isset( $instance['mtitle'] ) ? $instance['mtitle'] : '';
    $sc1title = isset( $instance['sc1title'] ) ? $instance['sc1title'] : '';
    $sc1 = isset( $instance['sc1'] ) ? $instance['sc1'] : '';
    $sc2title = isset( $instance['sc2title'] ) ? $instance['sc2title'] : '';
    $sc2 = isset( $instance['sc2'] ) ? $instance['sc2'] : '';

    // Get menus
    $menus = wp_get_nav_menus( array( 'orderby' => 'name' ) );

    // If no menus exists, direct the user to go and create some.
    if ( !$menus ) {
        echo '<p>'. sprintf( __('No menus have been created yet. <a href="%s">Create some</a>.'), admin_url('nav-menus.php') ) .'</p>';
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'wpspprofwid' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />   
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'mtitle' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Menu Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mtitle'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mtitle'); ?>" value="<?php echo $mtitle; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'nav_menu' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select Menu:' ); ?></label>
        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'nav_menu' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nav_menu'); ?>">
    <?php
        foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
            echo '<option value="' . $menu->term_id . '"'
                . selected( $nav_menu, $menu->term_id, false )
                . '>'. $menu->name . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc1title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 1 Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc1title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc1title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc1title; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc1' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 1:' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc1'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc1; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc1title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 2 Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc2title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc2title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc2title; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc2' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 2:' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc2'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc2; ?>" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that Wordpress does not allow you to use shortcodes in sidebars by default.

Have you added

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

To functions.php

Comment: No I don't want to edit function.php. and the widget will do the shortcodes if they are in the echo do_shortcode function the thing I would like is to be able to change the shortcodes via the admin panel and not have to rewrite the plugin every time shortcodes are added or removed